# Как поменять направление выпадания списка выбора типа карты yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как в yandex-maps-api сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выбора типа карты выпадающий список выпадал вверх, а не вниз?

[image]

```
map.controls.add('typeSelector', {
                    position: {
                        bottom: 25,
                        left: 380
                    },
                    float: 'none'
                });
```

К сожалению, при размещении кнопки внизу, список продолжает разворачиваться вниз и не виден

Comment: Увы, такой возможности сейчас нет.